# One of my cooks died, how do I get rid of the corpse?

Tags: prison-architect

When a prisoner dies it is usually transported outside automatically, but my prison's chef have been assassinated and its corpse have been transported to infirmary medical bed. After more than a week I think it's time to give him a proper burial, but I cannot understand how to do it.

[image]

Any idea how to solve?

Comment: Watch Breaking Bad and you'll find out...

Comment: Maybe he's only mostly dead?

Comment: Well he was the cook.....

Comment: Hire a doctor with the name "Miracle Max" and he should be able to revive the chef...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a morgue and from the picture I cannot see any problem with it, so it must be a bug causing the Cook to be left in the infirmary. One way to fix the problem is to edit the save game file but **remember to take a copy first** in case editing it causes it not to load properly.

Search for the text "Type Cook" to locate each cook in the file. For some objects the information is all on one line, other times it gets split into multiple lines, so use a regex like `Type[ ]+Cook[ ]*`. The reason to match spaces after the word "cook" is that otherwise you will also find all the `Cookers` in your prison kitchens.

Check for a line with `Damage` followed by a number, *I think* `1` represents full damage and any value between 0 and 1 is the level of injury.

E.g in my prison I have an injured Dog Handler

```
   BEGIN "[i 807]"    
        Id.i                 807  
        Id.u                 4708509  
        Type                 DogHandler  
        SubType              1  
        Pos.x                5.89334  
        Pos.y                17.7848  
        Or.x                 -0.810015  
        Or.y                 -0.586410  
        Walls.x              -1.00000  
        Walls.y              1.00000  
        Damage               0.0378701   << Injured
        Vel.x                -0.228300  
        Vel.y                -0.165277 
        ...
```

Changing the value to zero, or removing the line should bring the cook back to life!
If you have any problems add the section of the save game file to your question and I'll see if I can help.

**Original answer, before the question was updated showing the morgue:**

If you don't want to create a whole new room for the morgue you can allocate space in your infirmary for a couple of slabs.

Change the room type of the top part of your Infirmary to Morgue (red rectangle in my picture) and then add one or two slabs (white rectangles). The chef will be moved to one of them and eventually a hearse will arrive to take him away.

Don't worry about the doors being blocked, people will still be able to go through them.

If you start to get a lot of bodies piling up then you can build a separate, bigger, morgue.

[image: Mourge in Infirmary]

Comment: The problem is that I already have a separate morgue room but corpse is not moved there, I don't know why.

Comment: @Drake - OK, I saw your other comment about uploading a screen shot of the morgue when you get home. I'll wait to see that.

Comment: Screenshot updated. I tried put a morgule slab inside the infirmary after that screenshot but dead body remains there.

Comment: @Drake - Sounds like the game has become stuck with the dead body, I see nothing wrong with the room configurations. It may be necessary to edit the chef out of the save file if you really want to get rid of him.

Comment: I can edit the save file, but no idea how to move, any hints?

Comment: @Drake - I've updated my answer regarding editing the save file.

Comment: I was able to resurrect the cook modifying the savegame manually. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

You're going to need to build a morgue to put the body. A morgue must be indoors, and contain at least one morgue slab. I'd put a few more than one in there, however, because riots can get pretty nasty.

As of Alpha 11, a hearse will come to your prison, and the dead will be taken away for a proper burial. However, you still need to put the body in the morgue first.

Failing that, the game might have gotten stuck like this. Prison Architect is an alpha still, and one of the big things I have noticed is that sometimes, things like this get stuck. I once had a prisoner awaiting lockdown, sitting in handcuffs for months after his sentence was up. No matter how hard I tried, the guards wouldn't take him away, or even recognize him. If everything is set up correctly, and it still won't work, it's likely you've just encountered a bug.

Comment: I'm apparently really behind on these Prison Architect changes...

Comment: Your answer is fine, though.

Comment: I have a Morgue Slab very near to the infirmary with 4 containers and chef still stay there (I can post a screen when I go home)

Comment: @Drake Hrm. This might be a bug then. Sometimes, with the AI, things don't quite move like they're supposed to. I had a prisoner stuck in handcuffs for years after his sentence was up, and no matter how hard I tried to force a guard to move him to his cell and then release him, they wouldn't.

Comment: @peper757 Initially, I had a lot of really outdated information in this answer, if you look at the edit history.

Comment: @Unionhawk Ah.  Well, it's fine now, which is the important thing.

Comment: Screenshot updated

Comment: @Drake Hrm. Do you have a free guard to take him, or are they all assigned?

Comment: @Unionhawk I have at least 6/7 free guards

Comment: @Drake Yup, this is definitely a bug. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I know this won't matter, but the way to get the body away is to dismantle the medical beds and then remove the infirmary room. After the Hearse comes and the body is gone. Put back the beds and turn it into an infirmary again.

(WORKS ON MORGUE ALSO.)

I think the bodies get stuck on the beds or something.

Answer (score 0):

You might just not have enough guards to do all the tasks, save your game, add 20 or 30 guards and see if the bodies start moving, you need a morgue and a clinic doesnt hurt either. I was up to 1500 dead bodies and now they've all been cleared out. :3